# Props passed to child component are empty in constructor and componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs

I am just testing out various ideas and I do have experience using React, however, I seem to be totally missing something here.

In the `ParentComponent` I set initial state of an array within the constructor.

In `componentDidMount()` I then call a function to get some mock data which is just an array of objects. The function can be seen within `ParentComponent`. I then set the state using the mock data.

In the `render()` function of the `ParentComponent` I pass the array of objects as a prop to the `ChildComponent`.

In the `ChildComponent` when I try accessing the props within the constructor or within `componentDidMount()` the array is empty.

If I access the props in the `render()` function of the `ChildComponent` they are visible.

In React Dev Tools the props are clearly visible within the `ChildComponent`.

Does anyone have any idea why this behaviour is happening?

I need to be able to do some one time calculations on the data when the component is first mounted. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this?

In all other languages I am aware of, if you pass arguments to a constructor they are immediately available.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  this.state = {
    data: []
  }
}

componentDidMount() {

  const mockData = this.getMockData();

  this.setState({
      data: mockData
    });
}

render() {
    return (<ChildComponent data={ this.state.data }/>);
  }

  getMockData = () => {

    return [
          {
              key: 1,
              name: "Test1",
              price: "£0.00"
          },
          {
              key: 2,
              name: "Test2",
              price: "£0.00"
          }
      ]
    }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

---

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        console.log(props.data);
    }

    render() {
        return (return some stuff here);
    }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are populating the `data` array in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, `data` array is initially empty when it is passed as a prop to the `ChildComponent`. This is because **`componentDidMount` is called after the initial render**.

So, when `ChildComponent` is mounted as a result of initial render of `ParentComponent`, `data` prop passed to `ChildComponent` is an empty array. Once the `ChildComponent` has mounted, then `ParentComponent` is mounted. At this point, `componentDidMount` method in `ParentComponent` is called.

You see the empty array in the `constructor` because it is only called once during the initial render of the `ChildComponent`. `render()` method in `ChildComponent` sees the latest `data` array because when `componentDidMount` is called in the `ParentComponent`, it updates the state, `ParentComponent` re-renders, leading to the re-render of `ChildComponent` with updated `data` array as a prop BUT the `constructor` in the `ChildComponent` is not called again, only `render()` method executes when `ChildComponent` re-renders.

To see the updated data in the `ChildComponent`, you can use one of the following options:

- Use the `data` prop in the `render()` method
- Use [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) lifecycle method

  ```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     console.log(this.props.data);
  }
  ```

Logging `data` prop in the `render()` method will first log the empty `data` array because of the initial render and then it will log the updated `data` array due to re-render of the `ChildComponent`.

Logging `data` prop in the `componentDidUpdate()` method will only log the updated `data` array because it is not called during the initial render of the component.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Have you got any idea how I can make the data in the ParentComponent available immediately to the ChildComponent? Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You assign a data to this.state.data in componentDidMount which is called as React completed to updated the DOM  , so the props actually passed to the child component but their values in the moment of childComponenet construction still null because the componentDidMount still not called, and therefore the  "this.getMockData()" not called yet